# A sticky navbar with responsive design without SCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a navigation bar for a website I'm making, which I'm trying to make it able to collapse like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) on smaller screens, but also stick on the top of the page like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp) (or be displayed when scrolling back up and be hidden when scrolling down like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp).
I found a wonderful [pen](https://codepen.io/renanpupin/pen/ZGZmJe) on CodePen which does so, but uses SCSS, which I haven't learnt/used as of now.
I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this, aka without learning SCSS (and if anyone has a better idea for the navbar of my site, be my guest!)

Thank you.

Pen's SCSS code: (The question prompted me to enter code since I added a link to CodePen, don't fret by the size of it)

```
$break-width: 600px;
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section{
  position: relative;

  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav{
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
    transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.13,.15,.86);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.13,.15,.86);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
  .brand{
    /* padding: 15px 60px; */
    /* line-height: 30px; */
    line-height: 100px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
    transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.13,.15,.86);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.13,.15,.86);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    a{
      color: #E33B00;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* padding-right: 60px; */
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    li{
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      line-height: 30px;
      &:hover a{
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      a{
        color: #eee;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
  }
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    /* box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.22), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05); */
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    .brand{
      line-height: 60px;
    }
    ul li a{
      color: #6E7982;
    }
    ul li:hover a{
      color: #E33B00;
    }
}

.pattern-overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url("http://codemydesign.ru/CMDSpace/image/css/images/overlay.png") repeat;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.menu{
  display: none;
}


@media (max-width: $break-width){
  .sticky .menu{
    top: 0;
    .hamburger{
      background: #6E7982;
      &::before, &::after{
        background: #6E7982;
      }
    }
  }

  .open.sticky .hamburger{
    background: transparent;
  }
  .open .hamburger{
    background-color: transparent;
    &::before{
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    &::after{
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    }
  }
  .menu{
    display: block;
    outline:none;
    position:relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    float:left;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background:none;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 150ms;
    transition: opacity 150ms;
    &:hover{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  .hamburger, .hamburger::after, .hamburger::before{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 3px;
    line-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms;
    transition: all 150ms;
  }
  .hamburger::before{
    content: '';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background:#fff;
  }
  .hamburger::after{
    content:'';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    background:#fff;
  }
  .hamburger{
    background:#fff;
    &::after{
      -webkit-transform:translateY(5px);
      -ms-transform:translateY(5px);
      transform:translateY(5px);
    }
    &::before{
      -webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);
      -ms-transform:translateY(-8px);
      transform:translateY(-8px);
    }
  }
  /*.collapse nav{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-100%);
    transform:translateY(-100%);
  }*/
  .navbar{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 150ms;
    transition: transform 150ms;
  }
  ul.navbar{
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    /* transform: translateY(-200%); */
    li{
      line-height: calc((100vh - 60px) / 6);
      display: block;
    }
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .open .navbar{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);

  }

  .nav .brand{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
  .sticky .brand{
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  #nav{
    height: 100px;
    &.open{
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    &.sticky{
      height: 60px;
    }
    .open.sticky{
      height: auto;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Just convert the SCSS to CSS and you're done.

Comment: Is that tactic a good one? it does the work for now, but I'd like to build proper habits for the future too.

Comment: Well, in that case: learn Sass and set up a toolchain to convert SCSS to CSS.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the SCSS to CSS and you're done. You can even do it [online](https://www.sassmeister.com/) if you don't want to install the tools yourself. You can even view the compiled CSS in Codepen.

Resulting CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
  transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.13, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.13, 0.15, 0.86);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.nav .brand {
  /* padding: 15px 60px; */
  /* line-height: 30px; */
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
  transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, line-height, height;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.13, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.13, 0.15, 0.86);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  /* padding-right: 60px; */
}
.nav .brand a {
  color: #E33B00;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.nav ul li:hover a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav ul li a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.22), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05); */
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.sticky .brand {
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sticky ul li a {
  color: #6E7982;
}
.sticky ul li:hover a {
  color: #E33B00;
}

.pattern-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) url("http://codemydesign.ru/CMDSpace/image/css/images/overlay.png") repeat;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .sticky .menu {
    top: 0;
  }
  .sticky .menu .hamburger {
    background: #6E7982;
  }
  .sticky .menu .hamburger::before, .sticky .menu .hamburger::after {
    background: #6E7982;
  }

  .open.sticky .hamburger {
    background: transparent;
  }

  .open .hamburger {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .open .hamburger::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .open .hamburger::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
  }

  .menu {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    float: left;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 150ms;
    transition: opacity 150ms;
  }
  .menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .hamburger, .hamburger::after, .hamburger::before {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 3px;
    line-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms;
    transition: all 150ms;
  }

  .hamburger::before {
    content: '';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #fff;
  }

  .hamburger::after {
    content: '';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
    background: #fff;
  }

  .hamburger {
    background: #fff;
  }
  .hamburger::after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(5px);
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  .hamburger::before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }

  /*.collapse nav{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-100%);
    transform:translateY(-100%);
  }*/
  .navbar {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 150ms;
    transition: transform 150ms;
  }

  ul.navbar {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    /* transform: translateY(-200%); */
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  ul.navbar li {
    line-height: calc((100vh - 60px) / 6);
    display: block;
  }

  .open .navbar {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  .nav .brand {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }

  .sticky .brand {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #nav {
    height: 100px;
  }
  #nav.open {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  #nav.sticky {
    height: 60px;
  }
  #nav .open.sticky {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```